# Error al instalar AutoMapper en VS 2012

Tags: c#, automapper

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2012, NET Framework 4.6.1, cuando intento instalar AutoMapper me da el siguiente error.

```
PM> Install-Package AutoMapper 
Install-Package : 'AutoMapper' ya tiene una dependencia definida para 
'NETStandard.Library'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Install-Package AutoMapper
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: en el siguiente enlace que te paso sugiere actualizar la versión de NuGet :`nuget.exe update -self` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247961/nuget-package-manager-automapper-already-has-a-dependency-defined-for-micros Saludos.

Comment: He instalado esta versión Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 4.2.1

Comment: Hola Pedro. No sé si con tu último comentario significa que has logrado resolver tu problema (espero que sí), pero tengo entendido que para poder instalar la versión mas reciente de AutoMapper, necesitas tener un NuGet mas reciente que solo se puede obtener con versiones mas recientes de Visual Studio. Si no, tienes que usar versiones mas antiguas de AutoMapper.

Comment: @sstan Si, logre solucionarlo instalando la versión que comente 4.2.1, gracias por la información.